# How to insert a Qwidget inside Qwidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget

I am lost with all the parenting/initialising issues and have no idea why this does not work.
So I create a Label, then I create another Label with some painting in it, them I make a widget that contains the two, then I would like to put this new widget inside the main window... but nothing appears

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Labhtml(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QLabel('html')


class Bar(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(100, 5)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(0,0,200,3)


class Wid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        widget = QWidget()
        html = Labhtml()
        bar = Bar()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(html)
        self.layout.addWidget(bar)


class Example(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)

        layout.addWidget(Wid(widget))

        self.setWidget(widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for the class `Labhtml`, when you inherit from QLabel, you can use the methods and the attributes of the base class, or use the instantiation mechanism to pass some parameters :

```
class Labhtml(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText('html')
```

Then you don't need to create another widget inside the `Wid` class, but you have to refer to `self` instead :

```
class Wid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        html = Labhtml()
        bar = Bar()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(html)
        self.layout.addWidget(bar)
```

About the instantiation mechanism you could also write the classes by declaring a new `text` argument (the same used for the `Qlabel`), and pass it when you create your instance :

```
class Labhtml(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)


class Wid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        html = Labhtml('html')
```

Comment: Thanks. For the Labhtml QLabel I actually use an HTML file as subset. In the code above it happens that the Label does not show the all content of that subset, it collapses the HTML subset of that label. Any advise on how to avoid it and make so that the label adapts the dimension so to show the whole HTML table?

Comment: could you give an example of the HTML file used ? maybe create a new question if you didn't find any answers here, this could help somebody else.